# Comparison between two lists of words

Tags: python, nlp

I want to compare two lists (result, ground-truth). Output should contain 1 if both are match, if not '0' and output positive sensitive.  For example:

```
 result= [1,2,3,4,5]
 ground-truth=[2,4]
 Output= [0,1,0,1,0]
```

I implemented python code for this:

```
def comparedkeground(dke,grd):
    correct=np.zeros(len(dke))
    try:
        for i in range(len(grd)):
            a=dke.index(grd[i])
            correct[a]=1
    except:
        'ValueError'
    return correct
```

This code give perfect result for some cases: for example :

```
d=[1,2,30,4,6, 8, 50, 90, 121]
e=[30, 2, 50, 90]
print(comparedkeground(d,e))
[0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]

cc=['word', 'flags', 'tv', 'nanjo', 'panjo']
ccc=['panjo', 'tv']
print(comparedkeground(cc,ccc))
[0. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
```

But same code not working:

```
u=['Lyme-disease vaccine', 'United States', 'Lyme disease', 'Allen Steere']
u1= ['drugs', 'Lyme-disease vaccine', 'Lyme disease']
print(comparedkeground(u,u1))
[0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `u` array have no `'drugs'` value and output of the `dke.index(grd[i])` will be an error! You have put the `try` statement in the wrong place, you must change it like this:

```
def comparedkeground(dke,grd):
    correct=np.zeros(len(dke))
    for i in range(len(grd)):
        try:
            a=dke.index(grd[i])
            correct[a]=1
        except:
            'ValueError'
    return correct
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're running python3, maybe try:

```
def comparedkeground(dke, grd):
    return [int(i in grd) for i in dke]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because when the element does not exist in your main list, then an error occurs in the loop which stops the execution of the current for loop, but the rest of the array is not checked yet,
so instead move your `try catch` block a little inside like this

```
import numpy as np
def comparedkeground(dke,grd):
    correct=np.zeros(len(dke))
    for i in range(len(grd)):
        try:
            a=dke.index(grd[i])
            correct[a]=1
        except:
            'ValueError'
    return correct

u=['Lyme-disease vaccine', 'United States', 'Lyme disease', 'Allen Steere']
u1= ['drugs', 'Lyme-disease vaccine', 'Lyme disease']
print(comparedkeground(u,u1))
```

Output

```
[ 1.  0.  1.  0.]
```

I moved the try block inside because if the current element is not found then the next element should be searched in the list, so the loop should be present for the next iteration, so any errors that are there should be handled in the iteration itself.